# MongoDB $out Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect two API, so my scenario is **get** data from API_1 and then **post** it to API_2. I put the data I get from API_1 in **items collection**

```
db.items.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af4a47f3bfab813b9b7396d"), "poId" : "4739521", "sku" : "PTES02", "qtty" : 99, "prc" : 10, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af4a47f3bfab813b9b7396e"), "poId" : "4739539", "sku" : "PTES01", "qtty" : 13, "prc" : 99, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af4a4b573c9ab13ce2ef78d"), "poId" : "4739521", "sku" : "PTES02", "qtty" : 99, "prc" : 10, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af4a4b573c9ab13ce2ef78e"), "poId" : "4739539", "sku" : "PTES01", "qtty" : 13, "prc" : 99, "__v" : 0 }
```

I want to add the **Variant ID** from variants collections (which I get, from API_2) based on its **SKU** because it is required by API_2 in order to post, and both variant ID in API_1 and API_2 is completely different:

```
> db.variants.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af48bd03697230e01503eb2"), "SKU" : "PTES02", "varrID" : "40035121", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af48bd03697230e01503eb3"), "SKU" : "PTES01", "varrID" : "39183757", "__v" : 0 }
```

I tried this aggregation:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  { 
    $lookup: { 
      from: "variants",
      localField: "sku",
      foreignField: "SKU",
      as: "VardId"
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "VariantID"
  }
])
```

It creates a new empty collection named *"VariantID"* in database outside items collection, instead of this result that I want to achieve:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5af4a47f3bfab813b9b7396d"),
   "poId" : "4739521",
   "sku" : "PTES02",
   "qtty" : 99,
   "prc" : 10,
   "VariantID": "40035121",
   "__v" : 0
}
```

Please help me, GREAT GREAT Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create a new collection, or what exactly? `$out` creates a new collection. It's not clear what you are asking here or what your problem actually is.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, I am trying to get that VariantID to be a field of items collection

Comment: So you want to "update" the "existing" collection? Put the new field in "items"?

Comment: Yes correct! What do I do wrong?

Comment: `$out` cannot write to the existing collection. If you want to update the existing collection then you need to actually loop the results. If you use `$out` you have no choice but to have a new collection.

Comment: Okay @NeilLunn, Great thanks! Will try your solution